# Find the next power of two smaller than n in Julia

Tags: julia

I need to find the next power of two smaller than a given number in Julia.

i.e. `smallerpoweroftwo(15)` should return `8` but `smallerpoweroftwo(17)` should return `16`

I have this so far but searching through the string of bits seems a bit hacky to me. Maybe its not ... Any ideas?

```
function smallerpoweroftwo(n::Int)
    2^(length(bits(n)) - search(bits(n), '1'))
end
```

Thanks!

Edit:
I was mainly thinking is there a more elegant way to do this just using bitwise arithmetic. Or is there a bit length function somewhere like in some other languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia's standard library has `prevpow2` and `nextpow2` functions:

```
help?> prevpow2
search: prevpow2 prevpow prevprod

  prevpow2(n)

  The largest power of two not greater than n. Returns 0 for n==0, and returns -prevpow2(-n) for negative
  arguments.

help?> nextpow2
search: nextpow2 nextpow nextprod

  nextpow2(n)

  The smallest power of two not less than n. Returns 0 for n==0, and returns -nextpow2(-n) for negative
  arguments.
```

The `prevpow2` function should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?<sup>1</sup>

```
2^floor(Int, log(2,n-1))
```

---

<sup>1 <sub>added exponent to solution after comment by jverzani.</sub></sup>

Comment: I think: `f(x) = 2^(floor(Int, log2(x)))` is what they want, with the `2^` part.